# Unable to test controller in laravel?

Tags: php, testing, laravel

I am trying to understand testing in *laravel 4*. Created a folder named as *controller* in the test directory.

Added code

```
<?php
//www/Hututoo/app/tests/controller/PostsController.php

class PostsController extends TestCase {
    public function testIndex(){
        return $this->call('GET', 'testroute');
    }
}
```

and then wrote `phpunit` in the terminal. I was expecting it to show an error as `testroute` is not present in the route file.

It showed:

```
PHPUnit 4.1.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/Hututoo/phpunit.xml

.

Time: 128 ms, Memory: 5.50Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

So it didn't show any error. Then ,I deleted `ExampleTest.php` (was already present in the test folder)as i thought it could be preventing the test. This time the terminal showed

```
PHPUnit 4.1.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/Hututoo/phpunit.xml



Time: 42 ms, Memory: 1.50Mb

No tests executed!
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assert the outcome.

Meaning: You need to tell the test, what you're expecting that route should return. If you took a look at the example test case you would see this line:

`$this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());`

With that line you're telling the test, you're expecting that route to return a response, without any errors or failures.

You can also assert using HTTP status codes with the following:

`$this->assertResponseStatus(200, 'Your custom error message here');`

Where HTTP status code 200 stands for 'OK'.. meaning the resource that has been requested has been found, as you can imagine, if you're expecting a route to NOT return a resource, or not find one, or not exist at all, you could use:

`$this->assertResponseStatus(404, 'Your custom error message here');`

Where 404 as we all know, is status code for 'Resource Not Found'.

Here's a list of status codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

I hope I've made it clear or easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks. However i found out that my problem is occurring because my testfile name doesn't ends with Test. it should be PostsControllerTest.php.